# Can't compile C/Opengl program using g++

Tags: opengl, makefile, g++, cygwin, undefined-reference

I am taking a computer graphics course using opengl, and for the life of me, I've not been able to compile a single opengl program using the teacher's makefile without doing it on the school's server.  I'm not an experience C programmer, so make files are a bit new to me.  I've been spoiled by Eclipse compiler always making my build.xml file for me.

I am using cygwin since the teacher's make file is for linux/unix.  I have also installed opengl on it via searching under the Graphics category on installation.  This is my make file:

```
#!smake
#  Project 1: Simple scene
#

MACHINE= $(shell uname -s)


ifeq ($(MACHINE),Darwin)
        OPENGL_INC= -FOpenGL
        OPENGL_LIB= -framework OpenGL -framework GLUT -framework Cocoa
else
        OPENGL_INC= -I/usr/include
        OPENGL_LIB= -L/usr/lib64
        LLDLIBS = -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lGL -lXmu -lXext -lX11 -lm
endif

CXX=g++
COMPILER_FLAGS= -g

INCLUDE= $(OPENGL_INC)
```

While g++ doesn't complain about -lglut, -lGL, -lGLU, etc not existing (it was before), I still get this error message:

```
g++ -g -L/usr/lib64 -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lGL -lXmu -lXext -lX11 -lm  MyCoolModel.o 01primitives.o 01primitivesUtil.o trackball.o  model.o -o MyCoolModel
MyCoolModel.o: In function `init()':
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:48: undefined reference to `__imp_glClearColor'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:48:(.text+0x1b): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp_glClearColor'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:49: undefined reference to `__imp_glShadeModel'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:49:(.text+0x29): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp_glShadeModel'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:54: undefined reference to `__imp_glGenLists'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:54:(.text+0x41): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp_glGenLists'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:58: undefined reference to `__imp_glGenLists'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:58:(.text+0x6a): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp_glGenLists'
MyCoolModel.o: In function `Display()':
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:71: undefined reference to `__imp_glClear'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:71:(.text+0xa2): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp_glClear'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:73: undefined reference to `__imp_glPushMatrix'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:73:(.text+0xab): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp_glPushMatrix'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:76: undefined reference to `__imp_glDisable'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:76:(.text+0xbe): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp_glDisable'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:77: undefined reference to `__imp_glDisable'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:77:(.text+0xcc): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp_glDisable'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:80: undefined reference to `__imp_glColor3f'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:80:(.text+0xed): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp_glColor3f'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:82: undefined reference to `__imp_glBegin'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:82:(.text+0xfb): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__imp_glBegin'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:83: undefined reference to `__imp_glVertex3f'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:83:(.text+0x114): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:83: undefined reference to `__imp_glVertex3f'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:83: undefined reference to `__imp_glVertex3f'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:84: undefined reference to `__imp_glEnd'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:85: undefined reference to `__imp_glColor3f'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:86: undefined reference to `__imp_glBegin'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:87: undefined reference to `__imp_glVertex3f'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:87: undefined reference to `__imp_glVertex3f'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:87: undefined reference to `__imp_glVertex3f'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:88: undefined reference to `__imp_glEnd'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:98: undefined reference to `__imp_glCallList'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:99: undefined reference to `__imp_glPopMatrix'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:102: undefined reference to `__imp_glCallList'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:107: undefined reference to `glutSwapBuffers'
MyCoolModel.o: In function `Reshape(int, int)':
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:118: undefined reference to `__imp_glViewport'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:119: undefined reference to `__imp_glMatrixMode'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:120: undefined reference to `__imp_glLoadIdentity'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:121: undefined reference to `gluPerspective'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:122: undefined reference to `__imp_glMatrixMode'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:123: undefined reference to `__imp_glLoadIdentity'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:124: undefined reference to `__imp_glTranslatef'
MyCoolModel.o: In function `Mouse(int, int, int, int)':
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:133: undefined reference to `glutPostRedisplay'
MyCoolModel.o: In function `Motion(int, int)':
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:139: undefined reference to `glutPostRedisplay'
MyCoolModel.o: In function `Keyboard(unsigned char, int, int)':
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:158: undefined reference to `glutPostRedisplay'
MyCoolModel.o: In function `main':
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:166: undefined reference to `glutInit'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:167: undefined reference to `glutInitWindowPosition'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:168: undefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:169: undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:170: undefined reference to `glutCreateWindow'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:174: undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:175: undefined reference to `glutReshapeFunc'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:176: undefined reference to `glutMouseFunc'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:177: undefined reference to `glutMotionFunc'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:178: undefined reference to `glutKeyboardFunc'
/home/01primitives/MyCoolModel.c:180: undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'
01primitivesUtil.o: In function `uMakeCoordList(unsigned int)':
/home/01primitives/01primitivesUtil.c:35: undefined reference to `__imp_glNewList'
/home/01primitives/01primitivesUtil.c:37: undefined reference to `__imp_glBegin'
/home/01primitives/01primitivesUtil.c:38: undefined reference to `__imp_glColor3f'
/home/01primitives/01primitivesUtil.c:38: undefined reference to `__imp_glVertex3f'
/home/01primitives/01primitivesUtil.c:38: undefined reference to `__imp_glVertex3f'
/home/01primitives/01primitivesUtil.c:39: undefined reference to `__imp_glColor3f'
/home/01primitives/01primitivesUtil.c:39: undefined reference to `__imp_glVertex3f'
/home/01primitives/01primitivesUtil.c:39: undefined reference to `__imp_glVertex3f'
/home/01primitives/01primitivesUtil.c:40: undefined reference to `__imp_glColor3f'
/home/01primitives/01primitivesUtil.c:40: undefined reference to `__imp_glVertex3f'
/home/01primitives/01primitivesUtil.c:40: undefined reference to `__imp_glVertex3f'
/home/01primitives/01primitivesUtil.c:41: undefined reference to `__imp_glEnd'
/home/01primitives/01primitivesUtil.c:42: undefined reference to `__imp_glEndList'
01primitivesUtil.o: In function `uMakeGroundList(unsigned int)':
/home/01primitives/01primitivesUtil.c:51: undefined reference to `__imp_glNewList'
/home/01primitives/01primitivesUtil.c:53: undefined reference to `__imp_glEndList'
trackball.o: In function `_tbStopMotion(int, unsigned int)':
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:83: undefined reference to `glutIdleFunc'
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:87: undefined reference to `glutIdleFunc'
trackball.o: In function `tbInit(unsigned int)':
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:105: undefined reference to `__imp_glPushMatrix'
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:106: undefined reference to `__imp_glLoadIdentity'
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:107: undefined reference to `__imp_glGetFloatv'
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:108: undefined reference to `__imp_glPopMatrix'
trackball.o: In function `tbMatrix()':
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:117: undefined reference to `__imp_glPushMatrix'
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:118: undefined reference to `__imp_glLoadIdentity'
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:119: undefined reference to `__imp_glRotatef'
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:120: undefined reference to `__imp_glMultMatrixf'
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:121: undefined reference to `__imp_glGetFloatv'
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:122: undefined reference to `__imp_glPopMatrix'
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:124: undefined reference to `__imp_glMultMatrixf'
trackball.o: In function `tbMouse(int, int, int, int)':
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:141: undefined reference to `glutGet'
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:143: undefined reference to `glutGet'
trackball.o: In function `tbMotion(int, int, int)':
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:181: undefined reference to `glutGet'
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:187: undefined reference to `glutPostRedisplay'
trackball.o: In function `tbZoom(float)':
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:199: undefined reference to `__imp_glMatrixMode'
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:200: undefined reference to `__imp_glLoadIdentity'
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:202: undefined reference to `__imp_glTranslatef'
trackball.o: In function `translate(float, float)':
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:208: undefined reference to `__imp_glMatrixMode'
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:209: undefined reference to `__imp_glLoadIdentity'
/home/01primitives/trackball.c:214: undefined reference to `__imp_glTranslatef'
model.o: In function `ModelHead()':
/home/01primitives/model.c:18: undefined reference to `__imp_glPushMatrix'
/home/01primitives/model.c:19: undefined reference to `__imp_glTranslatef'
/home/01primitives/model.c:21: undefined reference to `__imp_glPopMatrix'
model.o: In function `ModelTorso()':
/home/01primitives/model.c:26: undefined reference to `__imp_glPushMatrix'
/home/01primitives/model.c:27: undefined reference to `__imp_glTranslatef'
/home/01primitives/model.c:28: undefined reference to `__imp_glPopMatrix'
model.o: In function `ModelUpperBody()':
/home/01primitives/model.c:33: undefined reference to `__imp_glPushMatrix'
/home/01primitives/model.c:34: undefined reference to `__imp_glTranslatef'
/home/01primitives/model.c:35: undefined reference to `__imp_glPopMatrix'
model.o: In function `ModelLegsAndFeet()':
/home/01primitives/model.c:40: undefined reference to `__imp_glPushMatrix'
/home/01primitives/model.c:41: undefined reference to `__imp_glTranslatef'
/home/01primitives/model.c:42: undefined reference to `__imp_glPopMatrix'
model.o: In function `ModelLittleMario()':
/home/01primitives/model.c:69: undefined reference to `__imp_glRasterPos2f'
/home/01primitives/model.c:70: undefined reference to `__imp_glDrawPixels'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:36: recipe for target 'MyCoolModel' failed
make: *** [MyCoolModel] Error 1
```

I've been hearing that this sort of problem lies with the linker, although I'm not exactly sure what that means.  I am assuming that my header files were recognized, my binaries weren't, or were in the wrong directory.

My teacher's Makefile says that the opengl library files are in a directory called /usr/lib64, but checking my cygwin user directory, it does not exist.  I can see the /usr/include folder, though.  This could the the problem, but I have no idea how to resolve it.  I though that installing opengl on cygwin would take care of this.

Assuming that this is the problem, could anyone help me locate these library files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You don't really "install opengl"; you install an implementation of it, usually by installing your graphics drivers, or a software rendered like mesa. I don't know how to access opengl32.dll from cygwin though.

Comment: The opengl libray files are not grabbed from System32, but rather, a local directory in cygwin.  A special version has to be downloaded and "installed" in cygwin before it can be used.  The purpose of cygwin is to behave like linux/unix system in a nested Windows environment.